# How to filter out softly deleted records?

Tags: cakephp, database-design, model, delete-row

Because data integrity have all records in database (PostgreSQL) table flag defining that particular record is (softly) deleted, e.g. `table_name.is_deleted = TRUE/FALSE`. I would like to filter out these records from all methods that returns data and do not include `is_deleted=FALSE` into `condition array`.

Is there some functionality / setting in Cake model to ignore such records?

Comment: Here is a [plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils) for you to look at. FWIW: Before I knew this plugin existed, I created SQL views that filtered on the delete flag, based Cakephp models on those views, then overrode the Delete method on those models to set the delete flag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like that. Use the History Table pattern. Copy row to history table on delete using a trigger.

Use something similar to this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus